# How to find instances when $d(a,b) = p^2$ for $p$ a prime.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Suppose I have a dimension formula (for a Lie algebra representation) given by 
$\mathrm{dim}_{a,b}  = {(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2) \over 2}$. I now would like to find pairs $(a,b)$ where $\dim_{a,b} = p^2$ for $p$ a prime? What are some techniques for accomplishing this? Should I try coding it up in python?

Comment: You seem to be looking at solving $(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2)=2p^2$ If $a,b \ge 1$ then the factors on the left hand side are all at least $2$. Looking at the prime factorisation of the right hand side, this would need to be $2 \times p \times p$. If $a=1$ (to give $2$) then $b=(p-1)$ and $a+b+2=1+p-1+2=p+2$. So, unless I have read the question wrongly, I don't think this can be done.

Comment: @JJR are $a,b$ in R,Q or N ?

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou $a, b \in \Bbb N$, sorry I should have mentioned these constraints. @ Mark Bennet: I'm sorry I think I may have misunderstood you. So your comment is that there are no pairs of the form $(1, b)$ satisfying the above equality?

Comment: @MarkBennet it appears after looking at your answer and the original problem more closely that there are no such $(a,b) \in \Bbb N$ that satisfy this for $p$ a prime. Do you know how I might find the integral points on the surface $F(a,b,n) = 0 = d(a,b) - n$ for $n \in \Bbb N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that
$$(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2)=2p^2,$$
with $p$ prime and $a,b \geq 0$.  Let's take $a \geq b$ without loss of generality.  If $a,b \geq 1$, then each term of the left-hand side above is bounded below by $2$.  Thus each contains a prime, and we may match up factors in descending pairs
$$(a+b+2)=p,\quad a+1=p, \quad b+1=2.$$
This contradicts that $(a+1)+(b+1)=(a+b+2)$, so we may assume $b=0$.  Our dimension equation now reads
$$(a+1)(a+2)=2p^2.$$
The prime $p$ cannot appear in the factorizations of both $a+1$ and $a+2$, so $p^2$ divides one of them.  The other factor is then bounded above by $2$, which bounds the whole left-hand side above by $6$.  Yet $2p^2 \geq 8$, a contradiction.